# Qt Creator Design mode disabled for Qt Quick / PySide6 project

Tags: python, qml, qt-creator, pyside, designmode

In newly installed Qt Creator 8.0.1, the Design Mode is disabled. I can only code in QML in Edit Mode.

I can easily reproduce the problem by just creating a new Python Qt Quick Project as shown below. The Design Button on the left menu is always disabled.

[image]

I tried to add all modules related to the Design Mode with  Qt maintenance tool, but it's still disabled.
I really get stuck on this configuration problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can enable the QmlDesigner by going to Help > About Plugins... and using the filter to find QmlDesigner. Activate the CheckBox and restart QtCreator.

https://www.qt.io/blog/qt-creator-6-released

> The integrated Qt Quick Designer is now disabled by default. Qt
> Creator will open .ui.qml files in Qt Design Studio. This is a step
> towards a more integrated workflow between Qt Design Studio and Qt
> Creator (video). Qt Quick Designer is still there, you can manually
> enable it again by checking the QmlDesigner plugin in Help > About
> Plugins.

Comment: I enabled it. Thanks Peter.

Comment: Another question if you don't mind.  I don't mind using Qt Design Studio if it is the recommanded method. But in edit mode, "The File should only be edited in Design Mode". So how to add a bridge to python slot functions in the QML file when we are in edit mode of Qt Design Studio  ? That is,  how to add in the QML file :  "Bridge { id: bridge}"

Comment: ... to be even more clear, here is the python snippet of my question : "@QmlElement class Bridge(QObject): @Slot(str, result=str) def getColor(self, s): ...